# Run a function in the background .js file from the popup .html file in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension. You switch between icons by clicking the Chrome extension icon, and the popup.html comes up with a preview of the icon you will set it to by clicking:

```
<input type="image" src="icon.png" onclick="helloWorld()"></input>
```

And the function `helloWorld()` is defined in the background.js file (same directory:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : "/iconcat.png"
});

function helloWorld() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
      path : "/icon.png"
    });
}
```

(the first thing that is being done is setting it to a cat icon)

I have both `icon.png` and `iconcat.png` in the same directory as each other and the .html and .js files.

How can I get the image button to run the `helloWorld()` function in the .js file by clicking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [By default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution), inline script won't be executed. You should extract your `onclick` inline handler and move it to external script like `popup.js`.
2. To call function in background page from popup page, you could take a look at [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) or [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

Sample code looks like:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Emoji",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Show an Emoji in Chrome!.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "picker.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

picker.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="inputId" type="image" src="icon.png"></input>
    <script src="picker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

picker.js

```
document.getElementById("inputId").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {
        backgroundPage.helloWorld();
    });
}, false);
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
  path : "/iconcat.png"
});

function helloWorld() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
      path : "/icon.png"
    });
}
```

Comment: So basically I should put the function (`helloWorld()`) in popup.js instead of background.js?

Comment: @Peanut, not exactly, `helloWorld()` can be still put in `background.js`, since you could call `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` to get background page and call function inside it.

Comment: @Peanut, what I mean is you should extract your inline handler to an external script, since inline script is not allowed by default.

Comment: And now I am confused with that comment. What if I let you see the GitHub repository with everything?

Comment: @Peanut, it would help a lot for debugging your issue.

Comment: The URL to the package is https://github.com/Usernamer/EmojiChrome. If you want to test it out, download the ZIP and unarchive it. Then you can upload the folder into Chrome.

Comment: @Peanut, you didn't include `picker.js` in your `picker.html` and forget to remove the inline handler, I have updated the answer, please have a try.